To prove that $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb R).$
To prove that $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb R)$ where
$C_0(\mathbb{R})=\{ f\in C(\mathbb{R}): \lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x)=0 \}$ and $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is the space of continuous functions with compact support with sup norm.
I tried as follows.
Let $f$ be any element of $C_0(\mathbb R)$. We want to approximate $f$ by elements of $C_c(\mathbb R).$ So Let us define sequence $\{f_n\}$, where
$$f_n(x) =
\begin{cases} 
f(x) & \text{if } x \in [-n, n], \\
-f(n)x + (n+1)f(n) & \text{if } x \in [n, n+1], \\
f(-n)x + (n+1)f(-n) & \text{if } x \in [-n-1, -n], \\
0 & \text{if } |x| \geq n+1.
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $f_n\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ and $ f_n \to f.$
Am I correct? Please check and suggest. Thank you.

Looks fine to me.

@geetha290krm Thank you .....

Yes, this looks good.
I also like the following construction: For $m \in \mathbb N$ let $f_m$ be the soft-shrinkage of $f$ by $1/m$, i.e.,
$$
f_m(x) = \operatorname{sign}(f(x)) \max\{ 0, |f(x)| - 1/m\}.$$
This has some further nice properties, i.e., the Lipschitz constant of $f$ is preserved.

Thank you..........
